# How to center a div in jspdf-autotable

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

How to center a div in jspdf-autotable. I am trying the following code but getting a result like a screenshot below and for details in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bablukpik/vh0g789L/28/)

```
// Header content function
    let header = function(data) {
        doc.setFontSize(18);
        doc.setTextColor(40);
        doc.setFontStyle('normal');

        headerHtml = '<div style="text-align: center;">' +
                        '<h2>Main Header</h2> ' +
                        '<h3>Second Header</h3>' +
                        '<h4>Third Header</h4>' +
                    '</div>';    
        doc.fromHTML(
            headerHtml,
            50, //x coord
            10, //y coord
            {
                useCss: true,
                margin: {left:0, right: 0},
                align: "center"
            }
        );
    };
// Auto table content options
    let autoTableOptions = {
        html: table,
        startY: 100, //false
        //margin: {top: 30},
        theme: 'plain', //striped, plain, grid
        cellWidth: 'auto',
        useCss: true,
        margin: {bottom:20},
        showHead: 'everyPage', //false, 'everyPage', 'firstPage'
        styles: {
            fontSize: 10.5, //14px
            font: 'helvetica', //helvetica, times, courier
            lineColor: [0, 0, 0], //or single value ie. lineColor: 255,
            lineWidth: .75, //1px
            cellPadding: 1.5,
            textColor: [0, 0, 0],
            fillColor: [255, 255, 255], //false for transparent or number or array of number
            valign: 'middle', //top, middle, bottom
            halign: 'left', //left, center, right
            cellWidth: 'auto', //'auto', 'wrap' or a number
            overflow: 'visible', //visible, hidden, ellipsize or linebreak
            fontStyle: 'normal', //normal, bold, italic, bolditalic
            rowPageBreak: 'always', //always, auto, avoid
            useCss: true,
        },
        didDrawPage: function (data) {
            // Header Content
            //let pageNumber = doc.internal.getNumberOfPages();
            if(data.pageNumber === 1) {
                header(data);
            }
        },
    };
    doc.autoTable(autoTableOptions);
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Can anyone help me?

I am sorry for any kind of unclear of the ask please let me know. Thanks in advance

Comment: please add html as well

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/bablukpik/vh0g789L/28/  @NagaSaiA

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below option of finding pagewidth and using it for x coordinate

```
let pdfWidth = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
```

Use half of that page width as x coordinate for header

```
doc.fromHTML(
            headerHtml,
            pdfWidth/2, //x coord
            10, //y coord
            {
                useCss: true,
                margin: {left:0, right: 0},
                halign: "center"
            }
        );
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/rbvdeE

Comment: Is there is a way of HTML with inline CSS support? @Naga Sai A